# How do I remove form pages from browser history in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a simple ASP.NET address book application.

In the application the user can:

- Get a list of contacts
- Click a contact to go to an edit-page
- Edit the contact
- Press save and go back to the list

Now: If the users clicks the browser back button at this point in time the application goes back to the edit page - which is NOT what the user expects (the user expects to go back to the page before the list).

The general problem is these temporary/edit pages that you would never want to navigate back to - is there a pattern for handling this?

Comment: you cannot affect the browser history with a web-page, can you imagine what would happen if it were possible ????

Comment: This is a browser restriction, not an ASP.NET (or any framework) issue.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API lets you do a few limited things (of course it's client side since it's all about the browser, nothing to do with .NET), but not sure you can do what you're suggesting. Have a read and see.

Comment: Anyway " If the users clicks the browser back button at this point in time the application goes back to the edit page". Isn't it? Have you got definitive user feedback on this? If I'm browsing, I generally expect to go back to the last page I was on, whatever it happened to be. If a problem occurred, I might well want to go back to it, or have some other reason for doing so. Anyway that's really just fundamental to how browsers work and I'm pretty sure there's not much you can do about it. Train/document/encourage your users to navigate using buttons and links you provide on the page, instead.

Comment: Maybe you need [POST/REDIRECT/GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern?

Comment: @MarkG: I have actually implemented the POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern which works fine - except when there are validation errors in the form. Then you have to do multiple redirects when the form finally clears.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions

1. Don't have separate edit page but use javascript to show edit form on detail page
2. When serving edit page check, that referrer header is not from contact list but from contact detail. If it's list page url then redirect to detail page

Imho option 1 is cleaner and option 2 probably easier

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Option 1 is tempting, but goes against the whole idea of using ASP.NET I think (it's just going to be too much javascript). Think I'll try to do some more experiments with referrer.